# Puppeteer-sharp - wait for download complete after clicking link

Tags: c#, xpath, puppeteer-sharp

I try to click a download link that triggers a file download. The click and the download works and the file is downloaded to the downloads folder.

```
string xpath = "//a";
IElementHandle ret = await page.WaitForXPathAsync(xpath);
await Delay();
await ret.FocusAsync();
await Delay();
await ret.ClickAsync();
await Delay();
```

After clicking on the download link, I need to wait until the file has been completely downloaded which takes up to several seconds before I can do something with the file. Its not a good solution just to add a delay as I have no idea how long it takes for the file to download.

How do I wait for a file download to complete in puppeteer-sharp?

Is there something like this?

```
await page.WaitForResponseAsync()
```

or

```
await page.on('response', (response)=>{ console.log(response, response._url)}
```

I do not know how to write this in puppeteer-sharp

Comment: can you share the url for the website you are testing please? thx

Comment: I cannot share the url as it is behind a login page, I can try find a similar page, might take some time.